# Using wp_get_post_tags instead of the_tags

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working in one theme, and i trying to sumit to wordpress theme page, but i have the follow massages:

> REQUIRED: This theme doesn't seem to display tags. Modify it to display tags in appropriate locations.

So i found that i don't have the_tags function but i have my own code with the wp_get_post_tags because i make my own html, so i dont know how to fix this problem.

This is my function

```
function basico_create_link($array_object_terms, $type) {

$link = '';
foreach ($array_object_terms as $object_terms) {
    $link.='<a href="';
    if ($type == 'category') {
        $link.=get_tag_link($object_terms->term_id);
    } else if ($type == 'tag') {
        $link.= get_category_link($object_terms->term_id);
    }
    $link.='" > ' . $object_terms->name . '</a>,';
}

return substr($link, 0, -1);
}
```

And i used this way

```
basico_create_link(wp_get_post_tags(get_the_ID(), array('fields' => 'all')), 'tag');
```

Answer (score 0):

Function the_tags() should be somewhere within The Loop. You can put it in your theme's index.php, although I myself would rather opt for single.php (since the tags are needed in blogposts).
Therefore, I start the loop, add some other content as needed and then I put the functions needed to get a blogpost properly displayed. In general, it could go like this:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <article>
    <!--some additional html/php content as needed -->
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <?php the_category(' '); ?> || <?php the_tags(); ?>
    <!--et cetera-->
```